# JQuery Validate Groups Success message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi I'm pretty new to the validate plugin. I'm trying to validate three dropboxes, date of birth fields, the trouble is the success message pops up after each field is changed regardless of whether the other two fields have been filled in or not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subscribe").validate({
        success: function(em) {
            em.html("<img src='/Themes/ChefAndBrewer/content/images/tick.png' />").addClass("valid");
        },
        rules: {
            day: {
                required: true
            },
            month: {
                required: true
            },
            year: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        groups: {
            DateofBirth: "day month year"
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "day" || element.attr("name") == "month" || element.attr("name") == "year") error.insertAfter("#year");
            else error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    });
});​

<li class="full-width">
<select class="required " id="month" name="month"><option value="">Month...</li>
<li class="full-width">
<select class="required day" id="day" name="day"><option value="">Day...</li>
<li class="full-width">
<select class="required" id="year" name="year"><option value="">Year...</li>
```

Comment: What do you want the behavior to be? Only to validate when the user clicks the submit button? Or only to display the validation message once for the three drop-downs?

Comment: I want the error/success meessage to appear after all three fields have been entered

Comment: There is no "good" way to know when the user is done entering data other than for them to click something else on the screen to alert you that they are done entering data. How will you know when all three fields have been entered? What if a user picks one, and then changes their mind and set it to blank and then go for a cup of coffee?

Comment: No, it's fine that the box has to lose focus before the validation takes place, the problem is, if you select a day, and ignore month and year, and then move the focus it validates the "Group" as success. the group shouldn't validate until all three boxes have been selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this answer [Validating broken up date width jQuery Validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056406/validating-broken-up-date-width-jquery-validation-plugin)

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<form id="form" name="form">
<select name="day" id="day">
    <option value="">DD</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select name="month" id="month">
    <option value="">MM</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select name="year" id="year">
    <option value="">YYYY</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="sub"/>
</form>

<script>
$(function() {


  // this function requires month day and year selections
  $.validator.addMethod("FullDate", function() {


    //if all values are selected
    if($("#day").val() != "" && $("#month").val() != "" && $("#year").val() != "") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }, 'errrr');



  $("form").validate({

  success: function(em) {       
                        em.html("winner").addClass("valid");
                },

    rules: {
      day: "FullDate",
      month: "FullDate",
      year: "FullDate"
    },
    groups:{
      dateofbirth:"day month year"
    },
    errorPlacement:function(error,element){
      error.insertAfter('#sub');
    }
  });    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `group` option of the validater is only used for grouping the messages, not the collection of rules. With the group you have specified now, there will only be one "required" messaged printed for all three of your `select` objects.

My suggestion is to remove the `group` and have each select with it's own required message which can override with the `messages` option of `.validate()`

I would also remove the CSS class `required` from the select because I'm pretty sure you are making them required by doing

```
rules: {
    day: { required: true },
    month: { required: true },
    year: { required: true }
}
```