# jQuery (or javascript) validate date Range

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Javascript, how do I make sure a date range is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971/using-javascript-how-do-i-make-sure-a-date-range-is-valid)

I am allowing users to input dates on the page, and one of my testers is correctly breaking the database save with the following error:

**SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.**

Is there an existing function out there to validate this on the client side in jQuery or JavaScript before the date is sent to the server so I can give feedback to the user? I'd prefer not to have to write my own (possibly incomplete one).

Thanks

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2056406/55209

Answer (score 2):

javascript overloads the `>` and `<` comparison operators to work with dates.

```
if (yourDate > new Date('1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM') && 
    yourDate < new Date('12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM')) {
    // date is in your valid range
} else {
    // date is not in your valid range
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/UB9NR/

keep in mind javascript validation is for *performance only* and adds no security; it should always be supplemented with server side validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try jQuery validation [plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to handle this at client side. **But do not do it only in client. Always Always Always Do it on Server Side before Sending to DB.**

As per the jQuery [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date), the code can be simple as this.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      date: true
    }
  }
});
```

If you want custom date format, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511439/custom-date-format-with-jquery-validation-plugin) is worth to look

Answer (score 1):

Use Datepicker plugin http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max
And restrict the user to input wrong range using date range method

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

**CODE**

```
$(function() {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [date js](http://www.datejs.com/) library. I think this function is what you are looking for **Date.validateDay**. see the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation)